# Any Machine Learning algorithm to know a yes/no answer?

Tags: machine-learning

Any Machine Learning algorithm to know the meaning of sentences? Specifically, I have sentences like, "we do not allow managers to trade derivatives", "We do not have policy on hedging", "our policy do not permit trading on stock", "trading is not allowed"... The actual sentence is longer. Any algorithm I can know whether trading on stock is allowed or not by programming? Thank you for your help!!!

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/watson/ ?

Comment: This problem is called [question answering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Question_answering).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do sentiment analysis for this task. Since the output is binary (yes/no) and there are obviously key words that will let you know whether a stock is available or not.

You could get very good results using an LSTM for the sentences that feeds into a final logistic regression layer to answer whether the answer is yes "1" or no "0". So you'd end up with an output probability of the question being answered "yes" or "no".

This guy did the exact same model (with a different dataset basically) using theano, I highly recommend looking at this tutorial (code is provided as well):

http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/lstm.html

All you need to do is build a dataset and get your hands a little dirty with python & theano.

If you want to go deeper, look into word embeddings.

Alternatively if that is too deep, you could just use a naive bayes algorithm. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_spam_filtering 
It has good results on spam detection & probably might be able to help with your task as well!

Answer (score 2):

I sounds like your need to consider Language Understanding services instead. There are a couple of providers of this type of service. The one I have used before is called LUIS from Microsoft:

https://www.luis.ai/home/index

It is not the algorithm you are looking for per se, but to solve your problem by implementing an algorithm, you need to develop a language understanding system using models based on deep learning neural nets, which is not a trivial exercise.